# How to get logged-in at the time of sign-up with Laravel-4?

Tags: logging, laravel, laravel-4

How to get logged-in at the time of sign-up with Laravel-4?

I was trying

```
if( $validation->passes() ) {

        $user = new User;
        $user->userName         = Input::get('username');
        $user->userPassword     = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->save();

        /*** if you want to logged in when registering ***/
        $user = User::whereUsername(Input::get('userName'))->first();
        Auth::login($user);

        return Redirect::route('home')->with('message', 'Thanks for registering');
    }
```

It gave me expection error

```
ErrorException
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple bug in your code:

```
$user->userName         = Input::get('username');
...
$user = User::whereUsername(Input::get('userName'))->first();
```

Pretty sure that second line should say `Input::get('username')` not `Input::get('userName')`;